# can't access class in same package

Tags: java, class, package

```
Project directory:
 Project
 -[other directories]
 -bin
 --A.java
 --B.java
```

Class A source code:

```
package bin;
public class A{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  B use=new B("Hello");
  use.run();
 }
}
```

Class B source code:

```
package bin;
public class B{
 static String x=null;
 public B(String text){
  x=text;
 }
 public static void run(){
  System.out.println(x);
 }
}
```

There was no error when I compiled B.java, when I tried to compile A.java, I got:

```
A.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
     B use=new B("Hello");
  symbol:   class B
  location: class A
search.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
     B use=new B("Hello");
           ^
  symbol:   class B
  location: class A
```

By the way, I am not using an IDE to compile this, I just edited the files with Geany and nano, then tried to compile them from the terminal with javac.

Comment: Did you import B in A?

Comment: @WaisKamal I thought you didn't need to import classes from the same package

Comment: You should describe how you have compiled the source files.  Most likely, you did not provide classpath parameter properly when compiling `A.java` file, so the compiler is unaware where `B.class` is located.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I did javac A.java in bin

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Alex, you are most likely executing javac command inside bin folder. The right way to compile the program in your situation is to run the javac command int project folder

```
javac bin/A.java
```

and to run

```
java bin/A
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming the current working directory is `Project`, the code shold be compiled as:

```
Project> java bin/*.java
```

This compiles all classes in `bin` into the same directory:

```
Project> dir bin
13.02.2022  18:20    <DIR>          .
13.02.2022  18:20    <DIR>          ..
13.02.2022  18:20               346 A.class
13.02.2022  18:14               117 A.java
13.02.2022  18:20               478 B.class
13.02.2022  18:14               154 B.java
               4 files          1 095 bytes
```

2. Run the code providing the package name in the class `bin.A`:

```
Project> java bin.A
Hello
```

---

However, to avoid mess in the source folder `bin` where the `.class` files are created by the compiler along with the `.java` source files, it would be better to provide a separate directory (e.g. `classes`) and refer it providing classpath parameter `-cp`:

```
Project>javac -d classes bin/*.java

Project>java -cp classes bin.A
Hello
```